# The lxml 'None' type is not None

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I want to compare a variable I set to `None`, which was a string element before, with `is` but it fails.

When I compare this variable to `None` with `==`, it works.

This is the variable I'm talking about:

```
print type(xml.a) -> <type 'lxml.objectify.StringElement'>
```

Because some libraries I use have `None` as a default argument (i.e., `def f(x=None)`), I converted my nullstrings earlier like this:

```
if xml.a == '':
    xml.a = None
```

Afterwards the type has changed to:

```
print type(xml.a) -> <type 'lxml.objectify.NoneElement'>
```

Which is not the same as:

```
print type(None) -> <type 'NoneType'>
```

When I compare this value as I described above I get the following result:

```
if xml.a is None:
    print 'what I expect'
else:
    print 'what I do NOT expect'  # sadly this one is printed

if xml.a == None:
    print 'what I do NOT expect'  # this one is printed again...
else:
    print 'what I expect'
```

I already know that when comparing objects that are not the same instance, `is` returns `false`. But my understanding is that I had set `xml.a` earlier to the `None` instance. On the other hand they don't match in their types and `is` returns `false` so it can't be the same instance as `None`.

- Why?
- Do I have no other choice than to use `==`?

For those who want to know more about the difference between `is` and `isinstance` there has been a discussion about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549801/differences-between-isinstance-and-type-in-python).

Comment: After WHAT was `type(xml.a)` changed to `<type 'lxml.objectify.NoneElement'>`?

Comment: After `xml.a = None`.

Comment: An alternate approach is to stop testing for None specifically and just look for "falsy" data, like `if xml.a`.

Comment: @tdelaney But if I have the Option not to do it, wouldn't it be better? Thanks to this [link](https://gist.github.com/jfarmer/2647362) I now know what "falsy" means.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are using the [`lxml.objectify` API](http://lxml.de/objectify.html#the-lxml-objectify-api); this API uses a *special object* to represent `None` values in the objectified XML tree. When you assigned `None` to `xml.a`, `lxml` stored that special object, so that it can transform that to a XML element in an XML document.

What you have is **not** the `None` singleton. You have an instance of the [`lxml.objectify.NoneElement` class](http://lxml.de/api/lxml.objectify.NoneElement-class.html) instead.

You can test for that element's type instead:

```
from lxml.objectify import NoneElement

if isinstance(xml.a, NoneElement):
```

Comment: Martijn: So the `lxml.objectify` API rebinds the name `None` to something else -- because when I try something like that in the Python shell I get a `SyntaxError: cannot assign to None`?

Comment: @martineau: no, assigning to an attribute on a `lxml.objectify` tree sets a specific `objectify` type object based on the value you just assigned. So assigning `None` to such an attribute is handled in a `__setattr__` call and stored as `lxml.objectify.NoneElement`. `None` itself is not rebound anywhere.